# How can I retrive data one by one per 15 minutes from my database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Like example I have 10 images in my database and i want to retrive first image when I retrive first image after 15 minutes i want to retrive the second image...

```
 database.addValueEventListener(object :ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for (data in snapshot.children){
                val image = data.child("myimage").value.toString()
                val voice = data.child("myvoice").value.toString()
                imagedatas=Data.Builder().putString("image",image).build()
                val model=automodel(image,voice)
                binding.recyclerview.layoutManager= LinearLayoutManager(this@AutoChangeActivity)
                binding.recyclerview.layoutManager= GridLayoutManager(this@AutoChangeActivity,2)
                binding.recyclerview.adapter=adapter
            
                arrayList.add(model)
            }
            val myWorkRequest : PeriodicWorkRequest = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<WallpaperWorker>(1,
                TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .setInputData(imagedatas)
                .build()
            WorkManager.getInstance(this@AutoChangeActivity).enqueue(myWorkRequest)
        }
        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {

        }

      })
```

[image: .]

Comment: Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?

Comment: I added this code so they wouldn't delete my question i dont know how to do this (Like example I have 10 images in my database and i want to retrive first image when I retrive first image after 15 minutes i want to retrive the second image...) Do you have any idea to do that?

Comment: Are you asking [how to run a periodic task in android](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+run+a+periodic+task+in+android)?

Comment: No I am not asking this @FrankvanPuffelen my database looking like this when user

Comment: I edit the question you can look now how my database looking when user select image

Comment: Like example the user select 97 image but i want to retrive id=1 image when i retrive id=1 image 15 minutes later  i want to retrive id=2 image